# Chen primes in the form p, p-2?

Tags: number-theory

In 1966 Chen famously proved there are infinitely primes *p* such that *p*+2 is either prime or semiprime.

Has it ever been proven that there are infinitely many primes *p* such that *p*-2 is either prime or semiprime?  Does it automatically follow from the *p*, *p*+2 case?

Comment: I found this in a different question.  I'm not sure it answers my question but I think it does: Although Chen's theorem is usually stated in the simple language of semiprimes, the proof actually yields something quite a bit stronger (see for instance p.483 of Opera de Cribro): there are infinitely many primes p such that p−2 has at ≤2 prime divisors, each of which is at least p^1/8.

Answer (score 2):

According to the reference [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chen_prime), Chen also proved the following generalization:

**Theorem(Chen)**: For any even integer $h\in 2\mathbb{Z}$, there exist infinitely many primes $p$ such that $p + h$ is either a prime or a semiprime.

So, for $h=-2$ we obtain the claim.